# How should we design database when working with multiple version of same service

Tags: spring-boot, osgi, microservices

For mricro-service based product,We want to provide backward compatibility.
This means we will have multiple versions of same service running at a time.

**Problem:**  When new version is created, there are changes in database TABLES, few columns are added and few are altered. In this case if database is same for services, it will impact older services. What is the best way to handle this ?
Can we have database tables with versions?

One known way is have different database for each service, which we want to avoid.

Comment: How about the data in these databases? Is it okay for a new version of the service to start from scratch with a brand-new table? And what happens if two different version of the service (concurrently running) try to access and update the same "entity"? Don't they need to interoperate somehow?

Answer (score 1):

You should never be in this situation. If columns are added you can have a DTO which do not send out these newly added columns to older versions. If you have to remove, then don't remove, stop using it for new apis, and if you need to alter create a new column and discard and let new api talk to new ones.

Having said that, such changes should be resisted and if you have to you need to make sure ways you can maintain the sanity of data. If you stop using and existing column and add new one how will you read data when you look up at the whole thing.
What will happen when new api makes call to historic data, what will happen when you run a reporting tool on it.

There are so many question that will need to be answered other than how api needs to be served and how services will manage the changes.

Creating a new table can be solution but how good or how bad it is , depends on your use case, what the changes are, what was the significance of the data in the service , what is its historic significance i.e if you need older data, or you can dump it etc

I feel like this is more of business decision rather than technical one.

As far as backward compatibility is concerned, I try to provide it at my controller level. I try as far as possible to have just one core biz logic in my code and map older apis to the newer one by either providing default values or doing required conversions.
I would never want to keep to set of logics. It takes some effort but I am able to find my way. Your case might not be same as mine, but still try to avoid getting into keeping two tables or two databases for old and new apis and try to concentrate the changes wrt to managing old apis into one place.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, its a very good question and design is tricky.

You should refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44360596/3850730) to get a fair and broad ideas.

> Can we have database tables with versions?

In my opinion, you can have whatever you want but this is not recommended because of kind of complexities that it introduces to the system. This is what is concluded in above answer too.

> What is the best way to handle this?

The way I do it and have seen in few systems that I didn't worked on that API is basically treated as presentation layer and incompatible DB changes to previous version of API are avoided.

i.e. lets say there is an API change in newer version which doesn't require a DB change - no problem , all is well and good - move ahead.

then lets say there is new API version which is calling for a DB change that will break existing system / old version - Its not good , try to rework your solution to achieve same functionality in such a way so that it doesn't break your existing version. If that's not possible ( obviously everything is possible !! ) , its a case of major product merge & upgrade and needs to be deferred till old version is discarded.

For this very reason, in the very first attempt, we need to design DB tables & JPA entities to be as complete and as broad as possible & keep DTOs and Entities distinct so changes are mainly needed on DTO side and not on entity side.

Obviously, these are subjective opinions, will vary case by case basis and open for debates.